Lubuntu 24.04.1 LTS - AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint driver
Tried libinput and synaptics drivers, neither seem to enable touchpad edge scrolling for me. Where can I download a driver specifically written for Alps? Something to try compiling locally myself?
Machine              : Laptop - Sony Vaio VPCEJ3T1E (2011 vintage) PCG-91211M
Processor            : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz
Memory               : 8112MB (878MB used)
Installation iso     : Lubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 (Downloaded 14th Sep 2024)
Touchpad (detected)  : AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint
???                  : Sony Vaio Jogdial (not physically present, but detected)
Kernel               : Linux 6.8.0-44-generic (x86_64)
Version              : #44-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Aug 13 13:35:26 UTC 2024
Palmrest & Touchpad  : Sony part no. 4FHK2PHN010 / (with CIRQUE/ALPS 1CA033 rushmore? touch controller)

